# Accessing cookies in WebApi ActionFilterAttribute.OnActionExecuting[Async]

Tags: cookies, asp.net-web-api2, owin, actionfilterattribute

Seems like a simple request, but for the life of me I can't find the request cookies anywhere.

```
class MyFilterAttribute : System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override async Task OnActionExecutingAsync(HttpActionContext actionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var requestCookies = ???
```

I'm stuck. I looked through all the properties I could find, and I even tried looking for various `.GetOwinContext()` extension methods, but to no avail. I'm sure there's an extension method somewhere that I'm just not finding (I gotta say, one big downside of extension methods is their lack of discoverability). Anyone know how to get the cookies out of the request?

Answer (score -1):

And almost immediately after posting, I found it:

```
using System.Net.Http;
```

...

```
var cookies = actionContext.Request.GetOwinContext().Request.Cookies;
```